# Can you identify the purpose of this control element and what control it belongs to?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Can you identify the purpose of this control element and what control it belongs to?

[image: grey bars appear in the left upper corner of my tab page]

I am using MetroFramework, an extension of the standard Windows Forms controls. When I click on these elements, they disappear and my contained controls are painted correctly. I'd really like to get rid of these bars when the tab page is first painted. They do not appear thereafter, even if I switch tabs.

Comment: are you able to `F12` or `F11` into the class(es) and debug have you checked their documentation or executed a google search to see if any documentation exist as well as examples

Comment: Yes of course.

Firstly, I wanted to make sure it's not something that is common to the underlying tab control that I have not seen before. The grey bars are active elements that can be hovered over and clicked. As soon as they are clicked they disappear for the remainder of the life of the application.

I know that it is painted over the top of any control added to a tab page.

There is no documentation for this UI toolkit that I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was part of the MetroTabControl. For my purposes I substituted TabControl instances and the "behavior" was resolved.